# Correct way to replace string with link

Tags: jquery, format

I am allowing my users to post messages on my website.  I want to be able to replace things such as %pop with a link that would be formatted as:

`<a href="ss/pop.wav">%pop</a>`

%explosion would change to:

`<a href="ss/explosion.wav">%explosion</a>`

I'm using jQuery, does anybody know how I would do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code doen't need jQuery:

```
"The %pop is here".replace(/%(\w+)/g, '<a href="ss/$1.wav">%$1</a>')
```

results in:

"The <a href="ss/pop.wav">%pop</a> is here"

Answer (score 2):

Using a mix of jQuery and regex:

```
jQuery("div.message").each(function() {
    jQuery(this).html(jQuery(this).text().replace(
        /%(\w+)/g,"<a href='ss/$1.wav'>%$1</a>"
    ));
});
```

Change the "div.message" selector as necessary.
Iterates over each div.message, and replaces each occurence of %foo as required.

Comment: This one helped me a lot to replace every match. Thanks evophage.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("a").each(function() {
    var href = $(this).val().split("%")[1];
    if(href.length > 0) {
        $(this).attr("href", "ss/"+href+".wav");
    }
});​
```

You'll want to tailor the selector to match your HTML architecture, of course, as iterating through all `a` elements on the page could be troublesome and/or slow. (I'd suggest using a class, for brevity's sake)

Answer (score 1):

Assign a class or rel to the  tag, loop through all instances to get the value inside the brackets, filter the % and assign the href.

```
$('a.get-path').each(function(){

    // Cache the $(this) object
    var $this = $(this);

    // Strip out the % from the "file name" and create the path
    var myPath = $this.html().replace(/%(.*)/, "ss/$1.wav");

    $this.attr('href', myPath);

});
```